# reactjs iframe not showing html

Tags: reactjs

I need to show a html page inside an iframe. I am using fetch to get the content because the page has authentication.  I do not receive any errors and I do not see any content too

```
someFunc() {
  const myIframe = this.refs.myIframe;     
  fetch('http://example.com/example.html', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Authorization': 'Basic xyz'
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
  }).then(function(text){
      //assign srcDoc to text
      return <iframe srcDoc={text}></iframe>;
  });
}
render() {
   return (<div>{this.someFunc()}</div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do: `<iframe src="http://example.com/example.html"></iframe>`?

Otherwise the reason it is not working is that the then is executed after the function is returned. So what you can do is create some state child and set it in the then function and render it in the renderfunction:

```
    var Example = React.createClass({
 componentDidMount: function() {
   var setState = this.setState;
   const myIframe = this.refs.myIframe;     
  fetch('http://example.com/example.html', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Authorization': 'Basic xyz'
    }
  }).then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
  }).then(function(text){
    setState({child: <iframe srcDoc={text}></iframe>});
  });
},
 getInitialState: function() {
   return {child: <div> hello </div>};
 },
render: function() {
   return (<div>{this.state.child}</div>)
}
});

React.render(
  <Example />, 
  document.getElementById('mount-point'));
```

Comment: I moved the fetch inside the componentDidMount and set the state of child but i still do not see the iframe.  inside render i did {this.state.child}

Comment: i edited it, i have problems with your fetch because of cors but basically it should work for the react site.